# Should images be allowed to scale when text is scaled in a browser

Tags: html, image, layout, floating, scalable

I am working on a personal website with more of an intention to practice good web development skills than anything. I am trying to build a cross browser( most of the modern browsers also IE6 ) and also hopefully a cross device ( trying to keep it the same in mobile devices ) web page. What i want to build is a 3 column floating layout design with header and footer.
Until now i have figured out a few good practices.. please correct me if you feel otherwise..

First and foremost is to keep the structure(HTML), presentation(CSS) and behaviour(JS) mutually exclusive. 
For scalability the best option seems to be %units over em units
Avoid using div's unnecessarily, to start a new line better use

tags
Best not to use margin for styling, when needed use padding

Now my issue is i have an image in my webpage. I have used only %units till now But if i use the %unit for the width of the image it wont be scalable. I can use em units for all of my web page and leave the image also scalable by setting its width in em units in my css.

But before i do that i wanted to know if its a good practice to let images scale, and also what will be the issues we face with such a design.

Thank you
Any suggestion or information on this idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Users can employ their browser's Zoom function to scale the site as a whole (including images). The text scaling function is meant only for scaling text - I'd advise against modifying the expected behavior.

Comment: May be i dint put it clearly. My question is if i press ctrl+ in a browser, then what is a good practice. If we use % the image wont scale along with the text, if em's are used it will

Comment: Well, the convention is to let the images scale with the zoom function, so if you're specifying the dimensions of your images then you should do so in a relative manner. The expectation of the user (or, at least, the intention of the browser) is to scale the entire viewport uniformly - text, images, everything. So, best practice is generally to avoid modifying the behavior of the browser. Hope that answers the 'should we' part.